# How can I generate a new variable that is the difference in value of the same variable across different years?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata of the following form:

```
 Individual Year  VariableX VariableY 
   1        2013   x11        y11      
   2        2013   x12        y12
   .         .      .          .
   N        2013   x1N        y1N
   1        2014   x21        y21
   2        2014   x22        y22 
   .         .      .          .
   N        2014   x2N        y2N
```

As can be seen above, the dataset is sorted by year. I now wish to create another variable `Z`, the change in `X` by `Year`, that is, for individual 1 for instance, her value for this variable should be `x21` - `x11` (her value of `x` in year 2014 - her value of `x` in year 2014).

Comment: What you have appears to be longitudinal or panel data. You would likely benefit from reviewing section 11.4 of the Stata User's Manual, as well as Stata Longitudinal-Data/Panel-Data Reference Manual included with your Stata documentation (version 11 and later, as a PDF accessible from Stata's help menu). The short answer to your question is that by taking advantage of the techniques documented in those manuals, you won't need to manually create the difference variable in order to use the difference in your analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with panel data, you can tell Stata how your data is arranged with:

```
xtset individual year
```

One way of accessing the the one year lagged value is by using the `L.` operator:

```
generate z = x - L.x
```

Other than that you should probably read up on manipulating panel data in Stata.